# Index error when drawing elements by index from list using random.randint()'s

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

```
import random
fruits = ['Apple','Mango','Banana','Grapes','Guava']
random.seed(500)
low =0
high = len(fruits)
random_fruits = [fruits[random.randint(low,high)] for i in range(1000)]
```

This is my code and following is the error what I am getting?

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: If you just want a random element from your sequence, use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice).

Comment: @zwer I think [`random.choices(iterable,k=number of elems returned)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.choices) would better suit his needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling one function 1000 times to get 1000 values. For [python-3](/questions/tagged/python-3) you can simplify your code by using [`random.choices(iterable, k=nubmer of elements)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.choices).

One call will give you a list of 1000 random items from your source-iterable:

```
import random

fruits = ['Apple','Mango','Banana','Grapes','Guava']
random.seed(500)
# reduced 1000 to 10 for output-brievity
random_fruits = random.choices(fruits,k=10) # no need to get 1000 times one element, get
                                            # 1000 back in one call is more efficient.

print(random_fruits)
```

Which gives an output of:

```
['Grapes', 'Guava', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Grapes', 'Mango', 'Guava', 'Mango', 'Banana', 'Grapes']
```

You feed it an iterable and a count and get the radomn drawn results (with duplicates) back as `list`.

---

Timings:

```
import timeit

s = """import random
random.seed(500)
fruits=['Apple','Mango','Banana','Grapes','Guava']"""

timeit.timeit("k = [fruits[random.randint(0,4)] for _ in range(1000)]", 
              setup = s , number=100) 

0.11539360368355066
```

vs.

```
timeit.timeit("k = random.choices(fruits, k=1000)", 
              setup = s, number=100)

0.02338418321748037
```

which makes using `random.choices(...)` about 5 times faster.

Answer (score 3):

Function `random.randint` generates a random number inside the range defined by low and high values, both included: `low <= x <= high`. Since you set `high` to `len(fruits)`, and the last list index is actually `len(fruits) - 1`, you can get a list index out of range error in case `random.randint` produces the high value.

Instead, modify the code by changing the definition of `high`.

```
import random
fruits = ['Apple','Mango','Banana','Grapes','Guava']
random.seed(500)
low = 0
high = len(fruits) - 1
random_fruits = [fruits[random.randint(low,high)] for i in range(1000)]
```

Comment: Or just use `randrange` with the original values (the implementation of `randint` is already `return self.randrange(low, high+1)`, so using `randrange` without subtracting is already faster).

Comment: @ShadowRanger That's true, thanks. I was focusing on explaining and fixing the original example, not as much on proposing alternatives, of which there are several.